# replace double backslash with single backslash in haskell

Tags: postgresql, haskell, escaping, bytestring

I want to replace "\\" from a bytestring sequence (Data.ByteString)
with "\", but due to the internal escaping of "\" it won't work.
Consider following example:

The original bytestring:

```
"\159\DEL*\150\222/\129vr\205\241=mA\192\184"
```

After storing in and re-reading from a database I obtain following 
bytestring:

```
 "\"\\159\\DEL*\\150\\222/\\129vr\\205\\241=mA\\192\\184\""
```

Imagine that the bytestring is used as a cryptographic key, which
is now a wrong key due to the invalid characters in the sequence.
This problem actually arises from the wrong database representation 
(varchar instead of bytea) because it's otherwise considered as an invalid utf-8 sequence.
I have tried to replace the invalid characters using some sort of 
split-modify-concat approach, but all I get is something without
any backslash inside the sequence, because I can't insert a single backslash
into a bytestring.

I really ask for your help.

Comment: You want to replace a character by itself? I can't understand. Anyway, double check you are not using some escaping functions inadvertently, like `show`, which add unwanted escapes.

Comment: How are you storing the string to the database? I think that's where your problem is.

Comment: @ErikR True, but I think part of the purpose of this question is to repair the damage to strings already stored in the database.

Comment: Please edit your question. StackOverflow uses [markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), not plaintext, hence your backslash-containing strings aren't shown as intended.

Comment: strip of the start-end quotes and cast them to bytea

Comment: The formatting is still wrong.

Comment: I have edited the question @leftaroundabout. I can't store it as bytea due to the invalid encoding. Moreover, it seems that storing it as SqlString and retrieving it - wich comes back as SqlByteString - achieves the "best" result, namely the aboved mentioned.

Comment: @chi, I am using show in order to obtain a string out of the bytestring. I have also tried to use the unpack function, but no different result.

Comment: show is meant to escape funny chars, unpack should keep the string as it is

Comment: Actually the data is stored correctly in the database, but reading from the database doesn't work properly. There must be some bug in the 'fromSql' conversion function. It's even worse when you need to handle both lazy and strict bytestrings as strict bytestrings are only supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps using `read` will work for you:

```
import Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS

bad =  BS.pack "\"\\159\\DEL*\\150\\222/\\129vr\\205\\241=mA\\192\\184\""

good = read (BS.unpack bad) :: BS.ByteString

-- returns: "\159\DEL*\150\222/\129vr\205\241=mA\192\184"
```

You can also use `readMaybe` instead for safer parsing.

Answer (score 0):

possibly you want the postgresql expression

```
substring(ByteString from e'^\\"(.*)\\"$')::bytea
```

that will give a `bytea` result that can be used in queries or in an `alter table`-`using` DDL